# How to compute the power of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to compute the -0.5 power of the following matrix:

```
S <- matrix(c(0.088150041, 0.001017491 , 0.001017491, 0.084634294),nrow=2)
```

In Matlab, the result is (`S^(-0.5)`):

```
S^(-0.5)
ans =
 3.3683   -0.0200
-0.0200    3.4376
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some time, the following solution came up:

```
"%^%" <- function(S, power) 
   with(eigen(S), vectors %*% (values^power * t(vectors))) 
S%^%(-0.5)
```

The result gives the expected answer:

```
              [,1]        [,2]
  [1,]  3.36830328 -0.02004191
  [2,] -0.02004191  3.43755430
```

Comment: You should explain where `vectors` and `values` come from, or in a few weeks (or hours) nobody will remember :-0

Comment: They are just the results of `eigen`.

Comment: Does this work for a matrix which has no eigen value decomposition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Matrices_that_are_not_diagonalizable ?

Comment: Wait, this `%^%` doesn't even work for square: with `A = matrix(c(0,1,2,2),2,2)`, the results of `A %*% A` (correct) and `A %^% 2` are **not the same**

Comment: Warning! This is wrong, and doesn't work in general. According to a linear algebra course, this solution would work with `t(vectors)` replaced by `solve(vectors)`, but only when S is diagonalizable.
It will also work in some other cases, for example if S is symmetric because then the matrix `vectors` is orthogonal, i.e. `t(vectors) = solve(vectors)` ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Diagonalizable_matrices)). That's why it works for the matrix given by original question, which is symmetric. But once again, for a random matrix, this fails. See previous comment.

Answer (score 10):

```
> library(expm)
> solve(sqrtm(S))
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,]  3.36830328 -0.02004191
[2,] -0.02004191  3.43755429
```

Answer (score 5):

The square root of a matrix is not necessarily unique (most real numbers have at least 2 square roots, so it is not just matricies).  There are multiple algorithms for generating a square root of a matrix.  Others have shown the approach using expm and eigenvalues, but the Cholesky decomposition is another possibility (see the `chol` function).

Comment: Indeed.  I tracked down this (obvious) page,  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix , and was amazed/horrified to find that the 2x2 identity matrix has an infinite number of square roots populated with Pythagorean triples!

Answer (score 1):

To extend this answer beyond square roots, the following function `exp.mat()` generalizes the "[Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse)" of a matrix and allows for one to calculate the exponentiation of a matrix via a Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) (even works for non square matrices, although I don't know when one would need that).

#### `exp.mat()` function:

```
#The exp.mat function performs can calculate the pseudoinverse of a matrix (EXP=-1)
#and other exponents of matrices, such as square roots (EXP=0.5) or square root of 
#its inverse (EXP=-0.5). 
#The function arguments are a matrix (MAT), an exponent (EXP), and a tolerance
#level for non-zero singular values.
exp.mat<-function(MAT, EXP, tol=NULL){
 MAT <- as.matrix(MAT)
 matdim <- dim(MAT)
 if(is.null(tol)){
  tol=min(1e-7, .Machine$double.eps*max(matdim)*max(MAT))
 }
 if(matdim[1]>=matdim[2]){ 
  svd1 <- svd(MAT)
  keep <- which(svd1$d > tol)
  res <- t(svd1$u[,keep]%*%diag(svd1$d[keep]^EXP, nrow=length(keep))%*%t(svd1$v[,keep]))
 }
 if(matdim[1]<matdim[2]){ 
  svd1 <- svd(t(MAT))
  keep <- which(svd1$d > tol)
  res <- svd1$u[,keep]%*%diag(svd1$d[keep]^EXP, nrow=length(keep))%*%t(svd1$v[,keep])
 }
 return(res)
}
```

#### Example

```
S <- matrix(c(0.088150041, 0.001017491 , 0.001017491, 0.084634294),nrow=2)
exp.mat(S, -0.5)
#            [,1]        [,2]
#[1,]  3.36830328 -0.02004191
#[2,] -0.02004191  3.43755429
```

Other examples can be found [here](http://menugget.blogspot.de/2012/03/exponentiation-of-matrix-including.html).